# Line 3:9: 'home' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here][1]

Line 3:9:  'home' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRjve.png

```js
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter,Routes,Route,} from 'react-router-dom'
import {home} from './page/home'
function App() {
  return <div><h1>hello</h1>
    <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<home/>}/>
          </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
 
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: You are not using home that's why it is showing. check the eslint config

Comment: i have been call it in route

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly brackets from your import. And I recommend following some basic unwritten rules like naming react components with capital letters and camelCase.

The curly brackets would make sense if your home.js/jsx/tsx didn't have 'home' as it's default export but I suspect that is not the case. So it should be import home from './page/home'

The curly brackets tell the app to do destructuring of home const form your home.jsx but if it's a default export, it won't work.